# Spark Scala - drop the first element from the array in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a following dataframe

```
+--------------------+
|        values      |
+--------------------+
|[[1,1,1],[3,2,4],[1,|
|[[1,1,2],[2,2,4],[1,|
|[[1,1,3],[4,2,4],[1,|
```

I want a column with the tail of the list. So far I know how to select the first element
`val df1 = df.select("values").getItem(0)` , but is there a method which would allow me drop the first element ?

Answer (score 1):

A UDF with a simple size check seems to be the simplest solution:

```
val df = Seq((1, Seq(1, 2, 3)), (2, Seq(4, 5))).toDF("c1", "c2")

def tail = udf( (s: Seq[Int]) => if (s.size > 1) s.tail else Seq.empty[Int] )

df.select($"c1", tail($"c2").as("c2tail")).show
// +---+------+
// | c1|c2tail|
// +---+------+
// |  1|[2, 3]|
// |  2|   [5]|
// +---+------+
```

As per suggestion in the comment section, a preferred solution would be to use Spark built-in function [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@slice(x:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,start:Int,length:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
df.select($"c1", slice($"c2", 2, Int.MaxValue).as("c2tail"))
```

Comment: What if it has just one entry for c2?

Comment: Good point @thebluephantom.  If `c2` consists of 0 or 1 element, `posexplode` (or `explode`) will generate 0 rows for the tail as expected, thus discarding the corresponding `c1`.  A UDF with size check like `if (s.size > 1) s.tail else Seq.empty[Int]` appears to be the simplest route.  It's unfortunate none of the `array_???` methods seems to provide a solution for something as simple as this.

Comment: the splice I think suffices

Comment: Ah, nice! I suppose you meant `slice`?  That would work.

Comment: sorry yes, also splice is a slice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think exists a built-in operator for this. 
But you can use UDFs, for example:

```
import collection.mutable.WrappedArray
def tailUdf = udf((array: WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Int]])=> array.tail)
df.select(tailUdf(col("value"))).show()
```